# What is meant by "staging instances" in this GCloud Debugger doc?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-debugger

What is meant by "staging instances" of your application in this Google Cloud Debugger [doc](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger/?hl=en_US&_ga=1.252468809.1792783146.1448297792#cloud_repository)? As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390305/cloud-debugger-with-google-app-engine) it seems that only the default version of an application can be used with Google Cloud Debugger. Does Google simply intend that you can use this with the default version of a separate application which you dedicate to your staging environment?

Comment: I agree that the phrase is unclear (esp. since "instances" means different things in app engine and compute engine and I don't think this phrase uses it in either of those two senses). I suspect your "simply intend" is correct, but I'll be working with my colleague in docs to get this clarified - thanks for pointing out the unclear phrase in question.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Debugger can be used with any module or any version of your running application.  The question you referred to is obsolete.

Many projects setup a module/version or simply another project to be used as their 'staging instance' to test their code before pushing to the production instance.  There is no one way to implement a 'staging instance'.

Answer (score 0):

The term **staging** in programming mostly refers to the term **development**.

In the app engine, you can have  multiple instances of your application. One in **Production** environment(one instance) and other in a **Staging** environment(another instance).

So **production** means that its a version currently running or available to the public. **Staging** means that it is running only for testing purposes (usually new features) before its being deployed to the public

Google saying:

> You can use the Cloud Debugger on both production and staging instances of your application

Simply means that you can you the Cloud Debugger on both the **Production** and **Staging**(***Development***) version of your application.